# Page not refreshing when modal is closed/hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal that loads after a button is clicked. What I want is that as soon as the modal gets hidden, refresh the page. but it does not seem to work as expected and don't see my error. What's wrong in my code?

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <!--Libreries for modal -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <button id="btn" onclick="openM()">Click</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalMSJ" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" style="font-weight: bold; color:black;" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" style="color:black;" id="MSJ">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                 
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
//refresh page when modal is hidden
$('#ModalMSJ').on('hide.bs.modal','.modal', function () {
    window.open('ModalP.php', '_self'); 
}); 

//open modal on button click
function openM() {
    $("#ModalMSJ").modal("show"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event binding is wrong, the hide callback is not called at all. Please remove the second param '.modal' as it is not needed. Final result:

```
$('#ModalMSJ').on('hide.bs.modal', function () 
{   
    window.open('ModalP.php', '_self'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try replacing:

```
window.open('ModalP.php', '_self');
```

With

```
location.reload();
//or
document.location.reload();
```

Comment: Thanks. But it does not work yet. It seems that `$('#ModalMSJ').on('hide.bs.modal','.modal', function () ` is not firing when the modal is hidden

Comment: Is this comment meant for me?